# How to achieve hot deployment in Tomcat 8?

Tags: tomcat, deployment, tomcat8, war-filedeployment

How to achieve hot deployment in Tomcat 8?

Hot Deployment : deploy a new war with out using the following steps.

1. Stop the server
2. Replace the old war with new.
3. Start the server.

Can I achieve this with out using ANT ?

Answer (score 0):

A hot deployment means storing a new war file in the appBase directory. You can do that with an ANT task as suggested by the documentation, or any other way to send a file at this place ( scp from one machine to another, move the file if it's local,..)